# Where is the best place to put my AdMob banner that will minimize misclicks?

Tags: placement, advertisement, android

Here is the current position of my AdMob banner:

[image]

Is this the best place? Because I have some concerns:

1. The ad may be too close to the FloatingActionButtons, although there is some space between the buttons and the ad.
2. The fact that these tabs are all scrollable lists makes me wonder about misclicks due to items near the bottom of the list and scrolling in general.
3. If I move the ad below the TabLayout but above the lists, there is a risk of misclicking due to the list items and the tabs.
4. If I move the ad up higher (after the title, but before the tabs), then there is a risk of misclicking if someone tries to click the tabs but touches too high. Or maybe they try to hit the three-dot overflow menu and hit the ad.
5. If I move the ad up above the title, there is a risk of misclicking if someone wants to pull down the very top gray Android bar that usually shows notifications for the phone. And likewise the same concern again about the overflow menu.

Where should I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends on what is best for you.**

Do you want users to click the ad? Or do you want users to complete tasks inside of the application?

See the image below. Almost the entire screen is clickable. There's a list, some icons and a floating action button.

I'd say, **keep the ad at the bottom of your screen.** When a user has a misclick it will only open the floating action button menu, which is not that bad. When putting the ad more up top the user will either switch tabs or change his selection, which is far worse than accidentally opening the floating action button menu.

[image]

Comment: "Do you want users to click the ad? Or do you want users to complete tasks inside of the application?" Personally, I want them to complete tasks inside of the application.

Comment: In that case, go with my advice. I'd personally want them to complete tasks too.